# angularjs ng-options nested variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, ng-options

Ng-options doesn't seem to work on object on $scope. for ex. $scope.model.colors.
Is it a bug or something wrong in my code.
http://jsfiddle.net/wbsrvc/uDteZ/#base

```
function Main($scope) {
 $scope.model.selected = "value1";
 $scope.model.colors = ["value1", "value2", "value3"];
}
<div ng-controller="Main" ng-app> <span>{{selected}}</span>

  <input ng-model="model.selected" />
  <select ng-model="model.selected" ng-options="v for v in model.colors"></select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing to create model object in scope

```
function Main($scope) {

 $scope.model = {};  //create model object in scope.
 $scope.model.selected = "value1";
 $scope.model.colors = ["value1", "value2", "value3"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tell the $scope.model it is an object

```
function Main($scope) {
  $scope.model = {};
  $scope.model.selected = "value1";
  $scope.model.colors = ["value1", "value2", "value3"];
}
```

Angular cannot find model without it being defined